# Differential-difference equation solution

Tags: integration, number-theory, recurrence-relations, analytic-number-theory

I have the following set of differential-difference equations
$$
\begin{aligned}
& (s F(s))^{\prime}=f(s-1) \text { for } s>1 \\
& (s f(s))^{\prime}=F(s-1) \text { for } s>2
\end{aligned}$$
with initial conditions $F(s)=\frac{2 e^\gamma}{s}$ for $1 \leq s \leq 3, f(s)=0$ for $1 \leq s \leq 2$

I want to show that the equations above are satisfied by
$$  \begin{gathered}
F(s):=2 e^\gamma\left(\frac{\mathbb{1}_{s>1}}{s}+\sum_{j \geq 3, \text { odd }} \frac{1}{j !} \int_{[1,+\infty)^{j-1}} \mathbb{1}_{t_1+\ldots t_{j-1} \leq s-1} \frac{d t_1 \ldots d t_{j-1}}{t_1 \ldots t_j}\right) \\
f(s):=2 e^\gamma \sum_{j \geq 2, \text { even }} \frac{1}{j !} \int_{[1,+\infty)^{j-1}} \mathbb{1}_{t_1+\ldots +t_{j-1} \leq s-1} \frac{d t_1 \ldots d t_{j-1}}{t_1 \ldots t_j}
\end{gathered}
$$
with the convention that $t_j:=s-t_1-\cdots-t_{j-1}$.

I am struggling to see how I can differentiate when the indicator is under the integral. I have tried a Dirac delta approach, as well as a recursive argument but I didn't get anywhere. Any pointers would appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly does the variable $t_j$ come from where you only have specified the domain of $t_1,t_2,\dots,t_{j-1}$?

Comment: @TravorLZH apologies, I forgot to include that part. We set $t_j = s-t_1-\ldots -t_{j-1}$.